# Perl - extract series of numbers with offsets from array

Tags: arrays, perl, extract, sequence

I am trying to search for series of numbers within an array of integers. For instance, if the array consists of the numbers `1,2,3,10,12,14`, it could be summarized to

1 to 3 with offset 1,

10 to 14 with offset 2

Below my code, where I loop over the array from the second element, track the offset between consecutive array elements and create a new 'series' if the offset changes:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @numbers = (1,2,3,10,12,14); #array to extract series from 
my $last_diff;
my $start = $numbers[0];
my $end;
my @all_series; #array will hold all information on series
for my $i (1..($#numbers+1)){
        my $diff;
        if ($i <($#numbers+1)){
                $diff = $numbers[$i] - $numbers[$i-1];
        }
        if (!$diff || ( $last_diff && ($last_diff != $diff)) ) {
                $end = $numbers[$i-1];
                my $series = { 'start'=> $start,
                            'end'  => $end,
                            'offset'=> $start == $end ? 1 : $last_diff,
                };
                push @all_series, $series;
                $start = $numbers[$i];
        }
        $last_diff = $diff;
}

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(@all_series);
```

Output looks as follows:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'offset' => 1,
          'end' => 3,
          'start' => 1
        };
$VAR2 = {
          'offset' => 1,
          'end' => 10,
          'start' => 10
        };
$VAR3 = {
          'offset' => 2,
          'end' => 14,
          'start' => 12
        };
```

This is not the desired result, since the last two series could be summarised into one (10 to 14, offset 2 instead of two series).

The flaw in the algorithm is independent from perl, however, maybe someone could give me a hint on how to approach this best, maybe there exist some perl-specific tricks for this.

In my application, all integers in the array are in ascending order and duplicate numbers do not exist.

**EDIT**
If single numbers occur that cannot be assignet to a serious, they should be a series of length one.

The more numbers can be summarized to series, the better (I want to minimize the number of series!)

Comment: Your specification is still vague. Take `1 2 3 5 7`: where should 3 go? Also, for `1 2 3 10 12 20 21 22`, do you want one series `10 12`, or make them 2 singleton series?

Comment: I had not thought of that. For the first case: In my application it does not matter whether the three is part if the first or the second sequence. For the latter case: `10 12` should be a series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the ternary operator. If you used plain

```
offset => $last_diff,
```

you'd notice that there is

```
$VAR2 = {
          'offset' => 7,
          'end' => 10,
          'start' => 10
```

Which is correct in a way. To avoid it, you can `undef $diff` after pushing to @series. It would produce the expected output for your case, but would still treat `1 2 3 7 10 12 14` as three sequences, starting at 1, 7 and 12. What you need is to make a longer sentence greedy somehow, now.

I experimented with the following, but you should test more:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

my @numbers = (1, 2, 3, 10, 12, 14);
my $last_diff;
my $start = $numbers[0];
my @all_series;
for my $i (1 .. $#numbers + 1) {
    my $diff;
    if ($i < $#numbers + 1) {
        $diff = $numbers[$i] - $numbers[ $i - 1 ];
    }

    # Merge with the last number from the previous series if needed:
    if (!$last_diff # Just starting a new series.
        and $i > 2  # Far enough to have preceding numbers.
        and $diff and $diff == $numbers[ $i - 1 ] - $numbers[ $i - 2 ]
       ) {
        $all_series[-1]{end} = $numbers[ $i - 3 ];
        $all_series[-1]{offset} = 0 if $all_series[-1]{start} == $all_series[-1]{end};
        $start = $numbers[ $i - 2 ];
    }

    if (! $diff or ( $last_diff && ($last_diff != $diff)) ) {
        push @all_series, { start  => $start,
                            end    => $numbers[ $i - 1 ],
                            offset => $last_diff,
                          };
        $start = $numbers[$i];
        undef $diff;
    }
    $last_diff = $diff;
}

print Dumper(@all_series);
```

Comment: Effective solution.  [`Confirmed`](http://ideone.com/grV9cb) it works for all the test cases, I could come up with.  Yours differs slightly from my solution in that it cuddles right (3 with 5) instead of left (3 with 2) in this example: `1,2,3,5,7`.  Also, if you change your undef call to `$diff = 0;`, then trailing values won't have an undef offset.  Ex.  `1,2,3,9`

Comment: Both answers work very well with my data, thank you so much! I will accept this here because it came earlier...

Answer (score 3):

This is most easily solved if done in three separate steps

- Determine difference between each number.
- Determine sequences of differences.
- Finally determine the ranges.

Each of these steps is done in order to more easily debug whether each step is correct.  Additionally, for certain values like `1,7,8,9`, it is necessary to look three numbers ahead to determine if `7` should be cuddled with `1` or not.  Therefore it helps to have already calculated all information in advance to more easily determine and specify the rules that are needed in the final loop to build the ranges.

To make the output easier to read, I'm displaying solitary numbers as just a `start` value.  Additionally, I added a `count` to the range hashes.  These changes are easily adjusted later.

For additional testing data, I added a sequence with a solitary 1 followed by a sequence of 3 numbers, and I also added a Fibonacci sequence for the challenge.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @nums = split ',';

    my @diffs = map {$nums[$_+1] - $nums[$_]} (0..$#nums-1);

    my @seq;
    for (@diffs) {
        if (@seq && $seq[-1]{diff} == $_) {
            $seq[-1]{count}++;
        } else {
            push @seq, {diff => $_, count => 1};
        }
    }

    my @ranges;
    for (my $i = 0; $i < @nums; $i++) {
        my $seq = shift @seq;

        # Solitary Number
        if (!$seq || ($seq->{count} == 1 && @seq && $seq[0]{count} > 1)) {
            push @ranges, {start => $nums[$i]};

        # Confirmed Range
        } else {
            push @ranges, {
                start  => $nums[$i],
                end    => $nums[$i + $seq->{count}],
                count  => $seq->{count} + 1,    # Can be commented out
                offset => $seq->{diff},
            };
            $i += $seq->{count};
            shift @seq if @seq && !--$seq[0]{count};
        }
    }

    dd @nums;
    dd @ranges;
    print "\n";
}

__DATA__
1,2,3,10,12,14
1,2,3,5,7
1,7,8,9
1,2,3,7,8,11,13,15,22,100,150,200
2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89
```

Outputs:

```
(1, 2, 3, 10, 12, 14)
(
  { count => 3, end => 3, offset => 1, start => 1 },
  { count => 3, end => 14, offset => 2, start => 10 },
)

(1, 2, 3, 5, 7)
(
  { count => 3, end => 3, offset => 1, start => 1 },
  { count => 2, end => 7, offset => 2, start => 5 },
)

(1, 7, 8, 9)
(
  { start => 1 },
  { count => 3, end => 9, offset => 1, start => 7 },
)

(1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 11, 13, 15, 22, 100, 150, 200)
(
  { count => 3, end => 3, offset => 1, start => 1 },
  { count => 2, end => 8, offset => 1, start => 7 },
  { count => 3, end => 15, offset => 2, start => 11 },
  { start => 22 },
  { count => 3, end => 200, offset => 50, start => 100 },
)

(2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89)
(
  { count => 2, end => 3, offset => 1, start => 2 },
  { count => 2, end => 8, offset => 3, start => 5 },
  { count => 2, end => 21, offset => 8, start => 13 },
  { count => 2, end => 55, offset => 21, start => 34 },
  { start => 89 },
)
```